# SymLink from Data Partition to Home Partition

Tags: partitioning, gnome, home-directory, symbolic-link

On reboot I have 
/home/tom which has fodlers: Desktop, Documents, and Downloads
Those are empty.
How do I browse and get the full /sda1/ path to the folders on /sda1/ which do have my files

Right now, using Files (Nautilus) I can't get to (don't know how to get to) /sda1/.
If I use

```
    "sudo mount /dev/sda1 /home"
```

then /sda1/ mounts as Home and I don't see the full path (e.g. Home/Documents, not /dev/sda1/data/home/documents).

My OS is in sda5
My data/files are in sda1

```
    tom@tom-HP-ProBook-450-G3:~$ lsblk
    NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
    sr0 11:0 1 1024M 0 rom 
    sda 8:0 0 931.5G 0 disk 
    ├─sda2 8:2 0 1K 0 part 
    ├─sda5 8:5 0 18.6G 0 part /
    ├─sda1 8:1 0 862.3G 0 part /
    └─sda6 8:6 0 50.6G 0 part [SWAP]
```

In Files (Nautilus) if I go to Other Locations it appears that only sda5 is mounted.

I should be able to run something like

```
    ln -s /sda1/data/documents /home/username/documents
```

but I want to confirm the details first

Comment: Things like `/dev/sda1` are *block devices* - you can't simply symlink "into" them. You **will** need to mount it somewhere (doesn't need to be `/home` - it could be `/data` or `/mnt/data` for example) and then symlink to locations in the mounted *filesystem*

Comment: I'm having a problem mounting sda1 @steeldriver

`tom@tom-HP-ProBook-450-G3:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 <br/>
[sudo] password for tom: <br/>
mount: /dev/sda1 is already mounted or / busy<br/>
       /dev/sda1 is already mounted on / `

Comment: Reinstall: Where is the "Mount Point" option | Some "Change Home Directory" instructions I find online are pretty confusing. I'm willing to reinstall, and this time correctly set sda1 as Home and sda5 as Root. I found a video where it appears that Ubuntu (with Unity) allows doing this but he selects Create New Partition Table, creates a new partition
Selects "Use As: EXT4" and
Mount Point: / (i.e. Root")

When I went to reinstall I didn't see the Mount Point option. Can I get that? Would I have to reformat the partition or Create New Partition Table to get that option?

Comment: In this video "The benefits of a Separate Home Partition" http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3WsX1OjqSE&t=4m43s

Comment: I reinstalled. This time I booted an Ubuntu Gnome Live Disk. At the Installation Type I selected "Something Else" and at the Partitioning screen I selected "sda1" then "Change"
then "Use as" set to "ext4" set it as "Mount Point" set to "/Home" and made sure "Format the Partition" was unchecked (Don't Format).

Then I selected "sda5" then "Change"
then "Use as" set to "ext4" set it as "Mount Point" set to "/" and made sure "Format the Partition" was checked (DO Format).

This is exactly what I wanted.